# How could I load other js scripts and run it with mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript

I need to write a bunch of queries.

And each query are sharing some `common data structure` or `function`

How could I load the `common.js` and use the `function` and `constants` in `app.js` (actullay I wrote it in coffee and then convert it into `js`)

I got the error by `mongo localhost:27017/test app.js`

> E QUERY    ReferenceError: leading_zero is not defined

## common.js

```
USERS = [
  '477  ',
  '4770 '
]

  leading_zero = function(num, size) {
    var s;
    if (size == null) {
      size = 2;
    }
    s = num + '';
    while (s.length < size) {
      s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s;
  };
```

## app.js

```
load("./common.js")
print(leading_zero(3))
print(USERS)
```

Comment: What does the actual JavaScript look like? Is a translated version of `common.js` included in your `lib-get-allergic-collections.js`? I would try loading your JavaScript code into the `mongo` shell first to work through any syntax errors, or include the actual `leading_zero()` function code in your question. The reference error suggests you haven't loaded a JavaScript file defining the `leading_zero()` function.

Comment: How is `common.js` being included? You have syntax errors in the user array (should be comma-delimited) but the function definition otherwise appears to be OK. Perhaps you are missing a line like `load("./lib/common.js")` at the start of your `app.js`?

Answer (score 2):

The function leading_zero needs to be on your db. Refer to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/ .

First run this on shell:

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "leading_zero",
     value : function(num, size) {
        var s;
        if (size == null) {
          size = 2;
        }
        s = num + '';
        while (s.length < size) {
          s = '0' + s;
        }
        return s;
      }
   }
)
```

This will save the function on the db as a system function.

Run db.loadServerScripts(); on shell once to load all scripts.

Then you can call it anywhere in the query.

```
print(leading_zero(3)) // directly on shell

db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.credits == myfunc(this.xValue)" } ); // on query
```